# mod_rewrite Unmatch of .php and Also Slash

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a set of rewrite rules that will send all requests for static assets to our CDN while keeping requests for PHP files local to the server.  I have one rule that works for "match anything but .php" but it also matches the slash or root of the site and redirects the initial request to the CDN.

```
RewriteRule !^(.*\.php)$ http://somecdn.com/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

I've been working on using RewriteCond to unmatch for the slash and .php files and I'm sure I'm just missing one piece.

```
RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !^(.*\.php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://somecdn.com/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

This works as my first rule, but still matches against slash.

How can I make it say "match everything but slash and .php then send everything else to the CDN"?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that works for my scenario was to move the RewriteCond out of the VirtualHost block and in to the Directory block.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.*\.php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://somecdn.com/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Adding the !-d to match anything not a directory had the beneficial side effect of allow clean URLs produced by our CMS to process locally instead of getting sent out to the CDN.